Setting variable which is key-value pairs via setState
Here I define a variable, data
const [data, setData] = useState({
        files: [],
        processed_files: Number,
        URL: String,
    });

Logging data works fine:
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {files: Array(2)}
1: {processed_files: 0}
2: {url: 'f179d744-cdfb-4546-b756-afb6d5daaeff'}
length:3
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)

I try to use setData in this way:
socket.on("send_data", function (...response: any) {
        setData(response)
    });

but further logging the keys in the dictionary says it is undefined:
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data); //this works fine (image uploaded)
        console.log(data.files); //undefined
        console.log(data.processed_files); //undefined
        console.log(data.url); //undefined
    }, [data]);

I then try this but it causes errors
socket.on("send_data", function (...response: any) {
        setData({files : response[0], processed_files : 0 as Number, URL : "" as String});
    });


Type 'Number' is missing the following properties from type 'NumberConstructor': prototype, MAX_VALUE, MIN_VALUE, NaN, and 11 more. ts(2740)
Type 'String' is missing the following properties from type 'StringConstructor': prototype, fromCharCode, fromCodePoint, raw ts(2739)

What should I do?

Use primitive types (string, number) instead of built-in types (String, Number).
Also, you should define the type in useState as below:
const [data, setData] = useState<{
   files: [];
   processed_files: number;
   URL: string;
} | null>(null);

socket.on("send_data", function (...response: any) {
    setData({ files: response[0], processed_files: 0, URL: "" });
});


wouldn't work cause data is a dictionary
'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693), same thing for string

Hi sorry for that, I had revise the answer. Thanks.

Thanks, I solved it by defining an interface, I never knew you could pull it off in a one-liner, ill keep this in mind, Thx again @Yong Shun

I have found out the issue, I solved it using an interface
interface serverData{
    files: Array<string>,
    processed_files: number,
    URL: string
}

const [data, setData] = useState<serverData>({
        files: [],
        processed_files: 0,
        URL: "",
    });


fixed the console log showing undefined like so:
socket.on("send_data", function (...response: any) {
        setData({files : response[0]['files'], processed_files: response[1]['processed_files'] , URL : response[2]['url'] });
    });

I should have also mentioned how i got my data (mb)
    socketio.emit('send_data', ({"files": files}, {"processed_files": processed_files}, {"url": url}))

